# How can I show full data in filtered gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have couple of dropdown lists to filter data from gridview which works fine but I want to add Select Any where it shows the data without the filter.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zwIw23t.jpg]

This is my SelectCommand in SQL datasource

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Courses]
WHERE (([Language] = @Language) AND ([Level] = @Level)       
AND ([endDate] = @endDate) AND ([startDate] = @startDate))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across similar situation once and I solved it building the `SelectCommand` at runtime. First add an option "Any" in your both of your DropDownLists which you will need to check in code behind.
Then check in code behind like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable";
String extndQuery = "";
bool and = false;
if (dropdownlist1.SelectedValue != "Any")
  {
    extndQuery += " Column1=@variable1";
    and = true;
  }
if (dropdownlist2.SelectedValue != "Any")
  {
    if (and)
    {
     extndQuery += " AND";
    }
    extndQuery += " Column2=@variable2";
    and = true;
  }
if (and)
{
  query += " WHERE" + extndQuery;
}

SelectCommand=query;
```